# Submitting form with JavaScript on selector change

Tags: javascript, select, onsubmit

I have added some code to automatically submit the form when a selector is changed:

```
            <select name="template" id="templateselector" onchange='this.form.submit()'>
                {{foreach $templates as $t}}
                    <option value="{{$t}}"{{if $t==$template}} selected="selected"{{/if}}>{{$t}}</option>
                {{/foreach}}
            </select>
```

The bracket tags come from my template engine.

When the page is first loaded, and an entry of the select list is selected, the form submits.
It then pre-selects the selected item in the list (selected="selected").

But when the item is pre-selected, the on submit action no longer works.
Why is that?

Comment: Select elements are not submit buttons, they shouldn't be submitting forms anyway. It isn't expected behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are "changing" from an item to the same item, which isn't a change.

Comment: I am not changing to the same item.
I just have preselected an item and then select another one.

Comment: I've changed the code now to this:

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#templateselector').change(function(){ 
  $("#editor_form").submit();
  alert("change event");
 });
 $("#templateselector option[value='{{$template}}']").attr('selected', 'selected');
 });
 </script>

The problem remains, though. On the first load of the page, I can a change in the selector will submit the form. After that, the form is not submitted when I select another value. The alert is executed on every change, though!